# FastAPI - How to implement customized Pydantic schema for every user

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

My goal is to use a customized `pydantic-schema` for every user.
Here is my Pydantic schema structure:

```
schemas/
    |___base/
    |       |___schema.py
    |              |___PydanticClass
    |___user_A/
    |       |___schema.py
    |               |___PydanticClass  //overrides base PydanticClass
    |___user_B/
    |       |___schema.py
    |               |___PydanticClass  //overrides base PydanticClass
    ....
```

My idea was to solve that with a `dynamic import` based on a user:

```
from schemas.{place here 'user_A' or 'user_B'}.schema import PydanticClass
```

The `'user_X'` (folder name) could be received from the `bearer token` or from the `session`, but I was not able to achieve that.

Second idea was to use a `decorator function` to override FastAPI's function behavior and the `PydanticClass` beavior:

```
@router.post("/create", dependencies=[Depends(auth.oauth2_scheme)])
@my_decorator ## should choose right PydanticClass based on a user
def create_something(data: PydanticClass):
    ...
```

I cannot figure out the right direction, as none of those ideas were able to handle what I want.

Other ideas/solutions are also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: The decorator is evaluated when the code is parsed (not for each request), so you can't switch it dynamically later (without support in the decorator itself).  You'd have to do anything like that as a dependency or in the controller itself based on logic you've defined (and read from the request) (the import would also run when the code is parsed, not when the request is handled). It'd probably be better to have some initialization code that runs through available schemas, imports the symbols and assigns them under a dictionary (i.e. result `{"user_A": user_A.schema, "user_B": user_B.schema}`)

Comment: @MatsLindh Interesting solution. Seems also much more performant then my ideas to import stuff on every new request. I'll try it out and let you know if I manage to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Now while thinking about the solution, this part will be problematic: ```def create_something(data: PydanticClass):``` as the typehint is still not possible to call during request.

Comment: You're going to handle that yourself, typehint `request: Request` instead, then manually decode the JSON and use `schemas["user_A"].parse_obj(request.json())` for example (or `**request.json()`, but I'm not really comfortable sending user controlled data directly to a constructor unless I'm _really_ certain about the implemented functionality).